# How to switch between Japanese input sources without all text being deleted from previous input source?

Tags: gnome, input-method, japanese

I am learning Japanese so I have installed `Japanese (Anthy)` through the `gnome-control-center`, but I have discovered something rather annoying, if I am typing in Hiragana and then I need to switch to Katakana or vice-versa, when I change input sources all the previous text which I have typed in the previous input source is deleted. How can I stop this so that I can switch between Hiragana and Katakana without having to do fiddly copying and pasting?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a solution to this that will work exactly the way you would like, but I can suggest a couple of workarounds to make working in Anthy more productive.

First, the behavior that you are seeing is really by design. While you are typing kana (of either sort), you are in pre-edit mode, which is a form of highlighting the text. When you switch the input mode, it's like typing over any highlighted text and causing it to disappear.

The solution is really -- before switching the mode -- to just to remove by highlighting by *converting* the current text via <kbd>space</kbd> and/or *committing* the text via <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once the text has been committed, it's not going anywhere.

The key here is to keep in mind that the various kana modes are separate sub-input modes, although this does mean that you might not be able to make as long a sentence as you might have wished that combines hiragana and katakana.

When you have typed in one mode and wish to change *everything* you've typed to another mode, you can use the function keys without losing what you have already typed:

- <kbd>F6</kbd> converts to hiragana.
- <kbd>F7</kbd> converts to katakana.
- <kbd>F8</kbd> converts half-width katakana.
- <kbd>F9</kbd> converts to full-width romaji.
- <kbd>F10</kbd> converts to romaji.

The above only convert text that has already been typed.

Unfortunately, there is no default keyboard setting to switch between the input modes, but rather than mousing up to the ibus menu on the top bar each time, you can set the keyboard shortcuts in:

```
Preferences -- Anthy >> Keybinding tab >> hiragana mode (and a separate katakana mode)
```

And, finally, a good option when you are only entering a small amount of katakana in a larger string of hiragana/kanji is to simply type the word you want in hiragana, then convert via the space bar and choose the katakana version that appears in the list of candidates.